# Minimum Cover for Function Dependencies

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

Im kinda struggling to understand the concept of minimal cover so i want to know if i got it right, Is it true to say that :

Given a Relation R with attributes A1...An

if  G is a minimal cover of FDs set F then for every subset X of attributes in R the closure of X in F, is the same as the closure of X in G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of closure you're right, you can see it as a semplification of a series of FDs:
if you have `F = {A->B, B->C, A->C}` the FD `A->C` is redudant because it could be derived from the first two FDs.
In this case the minimal cover G for F is `{A->B, B->C}`.